# Creating a hash table representation using an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, chaining

How do I make a hash table representation using an array in C++ for a table and apply a hash function such as `k % 10` to it? I'm to use chaining to resolve collision (i.e. the table is an array of linked lists).

I am to also insert, search, and delete values into/from this table.

So far, I have:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
}; 

void insert(int n, Node* hashtable[]) {

    int x = n % 10;
... ...
```

Say for example for the value `10`, my hash function would produce `0`, so `10` goes into the first slot of the array/hash table. 

Then if I had the value `100`, `100` would also go to the first slot, so my `10` would "point" to `100`... how would I code this?

Comment: If you have touched hashing, surely you have learned about linked list? Because linked list is even more basic than hashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
Node* oldFront = hashtable[hashcode];
Node* newNode = new Node(value, oldFront);
hashtable[hashcode] = newNode;
```

This will add the most recent collision to the front of the linked list, i.e. it operates as a stack. Adding it to the back is left as an exercise for the questioner!

Comment: Say I wanted to put something in my array of linked lists in a certain location (e.g. I wanted to put "2" in myarray[2]. myarray[2] may already have a value(s) there. How would I do that?)

Comment: You add it to the linked list that's in myarray[2].